# ArcGIS 10 restricted WEIGHTED Flow Accumulation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, hydrology, flow-accumulation

I have a question very similar to [one asked by wxfox4god on 12th June 2013 ("Arcmap 10 restrict Flow Accumulation")](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63160/arcmap-10-restrict-flow-accumulation) that was answered by whuber. (I have had to post it as a new question as I do not have the reputation to post a comment.)

The original question was about performing a version of the ArcGIS flow accumulation tool that is restricted to only accumulating cells from within a given distance. So for every cell in the raster the process finds how many cells within a certain distance would flow into that cell. whuber suggested a clever workaround using focal statistics iteratively.

However, my problem differs in that I need to find the weighted flow accumulation for every cell in the raster based on cells only within a certain distance. So for every cell in the raster I need to know the sum of all of the values from the cells that flow into that raster from within a specified distance.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as before?  How exactly does your distance restriction differ from the original one?

Comment: Hi. The same distance restriction applies but it is how to apply the distance restriction method you suggested to an accumulation weighted by another raster (rather than just accumulation of cells). 

I think I have worked out a way to do it on paper...

Comment: Finding the focal sum of the raster that the weighting is based on for irregular neighbourhoods focusing on each of the 8 directions, and then multiplying each of these by the outputs of your logical comparison between the directional irregular neighbourhood focal sums and each of the direction number (1 s and 0s) to identify the raster values that would be accumulated from each of the eight directions.

Hopefully this is correct? I now need to learn how to use ModelBuilder to make it happen.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the weights mean and how they are supposed to work?

Comment: Applying a flow accumulation using a weighted raster means that you are summing the weighted raster values from within all of the contributing cells, rather than just counting the number of contributing cells. It is useful for applications such as predicting pollutant concentrations within a river catchment - when the weighted raster would be the concentration of pollutants in the soil of each cell.

Comment: It's still not apparent what that means. An ordinary flow accumulation already is "weighted" in the sense that it may begin with any distribution of values (thought of as "rainfall intensities," if you wish). It then tracks them as they flow across the landscape at a constant rate. Another form of weighting would multiply the amount of flow out of a cell (at each step) according to some value in a weight raster at that cell.  Yet another would multiply each cumulative increment by a value that changes over time. Any (or all) of these could be relevant to modeling pollutant concentrations.

Comment: Apologies if I have not made myself clear. The weighting I am referring to is the same as that available as an option within the normal ArcGIS 'Flow Accumulation' tool.

As indicated above, I believe I have found a solution by adding an additional irregular neighbourhood focal sum raster stage to the process you described to answer wx4fox4god's original question. Hopefully I can find my own way from here.

Thanks for taking the time to reply anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The ArcGIS terminology is misleading, because their "weight" is really just an *initial condition* describing the amount of water originally in each cell. The possibility of having varying weights therefore does not change any of the algorithms at all--it only changes one of the inputs. The purpose of an irregular focal sum in your solution is a mystery to me; it's difficult to see how that could be used to implement a flow accumulation algorithm correctly.