# Does this ArcGIS flow accumulation example have an error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, algorithm, hydrology, watershed, flow-accumulation

The lower right corner of the [flow accumulation example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_Flow_Accumulation_works/009z00000062000000/) in ArcGIS Desktop's documentation has a flow accumulation value of 2.

However, I only see one cell flowing into the lower right corner (the cell immediately above):

[image]

Is there some nuance to the algorithm that I'm missing that would result in the flow accumulation being equal to 2 at this cell?

I don't care about the software being used - just the example/algorithm.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I'm not sure the argis-desktop tag is appropriate. I don't care about the software. Just teh example/algorithm.

Comment: I've edited accordingly but I think having the [tag:arcgis-desktop] tag would have been more likely to bring your question to the attention of whoever authored and/or is responsible for that page of documentation.

Comment: @PolyGeo That's an excellent. I trust your judgement on that.

Comment: ESRI changed it's name/branding to Esri several years - but questions here are almost always about GIS software (or algorithms) rather than GIS companies so I would have left that out too.

Comment: Yes, you're right, there is only one cell flowing into the lower right cell *that is shown on this graphic* when taken in isolation it would seem that the value should be 1. Well spotted, perhaps write Esri a note showing them the error and it might get fixed for future releases.

Comment: In an answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/63338/664 I worked through this example in detail, pointed out the error, and derived the correct answer.  There is more than one error, BTW.

Comment: thanks @whuber that a very helpful write. fwiw, here's what i'm working on: https://github.com/phobson/watershed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an error. Your link and presumably image source is the 10.0 help. The error is still present in the [10.1 help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/How_Flow_Accumulation_works/009z00000062000000/). However in the [10.2 help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000062000000), it has been corrected to show only a 1.

[image]

It's also worth noting that if you work through the math matrix as whuber has done at [Arcmap 10 restrict Flow Accumulation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63160/arcmap-10-restrict-flow-accumulation/63338#63338), that error is apparent as well as the adjacent 35 value being incorrect, though *that* has not been corrected in the latest version of the graphic (it should be 27).

Comment: Thanks. I'm not an ESRI products user, and all of my googling took me to 10.0 and 10.1 pages.

Comment: @PaulH I've also noticed that Google results tend to favor 10.0 and to a slightly lesser degree 10.1. I imagine because of indexing and how long they've been around. But you do still run across 9.x and 10.2 results as well. Easiest thing to do is also specify a version as a search term - a specific one if you're looking for it or the 'latest' for 'current' help (though I notice 10.3 isn't showing up yet, possibly because of Esri page/site restructuring, time it's been available, or search engine mechanics).